# Php odbc field name longer than 31 characters

Tags: php, odbc

Is there a way to allow php odbc field name longer than 31 characters? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-field-name.php#79354) on the documentation page for odbc_field_name, you can change the source code and recompile PHP to get around the 31-character limitation.